# Do I need to close the tab when using scrapy playwrigth?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, playwright

Edit: Got the answer. The autothrottle was limited to default. Now I need to limit it to the number of website pages. The code looks like this `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 3`

I am using scrapy playwright. I want to loop through some sites. The scrapy spider will request to extract data through each website link. After rendering through each request, do I need to close the tab?
like using this:

```
def parse(self, response):
page = response.meta["playwright_page"]
await page.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Got the answer. The autothrottle was limited to default. Now I need to limit it to the number of website pages. The code looks like this `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 3`